# Generate new or change a line color with Postscript notation

Tags: color, pstricks, postscript

I'd like to use

```
\psset{linecolor = blue!\mapDFVtoColor}
```

whereas `\mapDFVtoColor` is defined as something like

```
\def\mapDFVtoColor{20 40 add 3.5 div}
```

Here's a bit longer but condensed example

```
\documentclass[dvips]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks, pstricks-add}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid = true](-4.5, -4.5)(4.5, 5)
    \def\radius{4\space}
    \def\Adeg{68\space}
    \def\Bdeg{30\space}

    \def\xp{2\space}
    \def\yp{1\space}
    \def\zp{1\space}

    \def\DistanceFromViewer{%
    \radius \Bdeg cos \Adeg sin mul mul \xp mul %
    \radius \Adeg cos \Bdeg cos mul mul \yp mul add %
    \radius \Bdeg sin mul \zp mul add %
    \radius dup mul sub abs %
    \radius div\space}

    \def\MinDist{0\space}
    \def\MaxDist{\radius 2 mul\space}
    \def\MinColor{40\space}
    \def\MaxColor{100\space}

    \def\mapDFVtoColor{%
    \DistanceFromViewer \MinDist sub %
    \MaxColor \MinColor sub mul %
    \MaxDist \MinDist sub div %
    \MinColor add}

    \rput(1, 1){Distance: \psPrintValue{\DistanceFromViewer}}
    \rput(1, 0){Map: \psPrintValue{\mapDFVtoColor}}

    \psset{linecolor = blue!\mapDFVtoColor}

\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

The idea is that I want to scale the colour of a point in 3D with the distance to the observer. Thanks for comments.

Comment: If I try seeing what's the value of `\mapDFVtoColor` at the point of usage, I see `4 30 cos 68 sin mul mul 2 mul 4 68 cos 30 cos mul mul 1 mul add 4 30 sin mul 1 mul add 4 dup mul sub abs 4 div 0 sub 100 40 sub mul 4 2 mul 0 sub div 40 add` which clearly is not something good for the `xcolor` syntax `blue!<number>` you want to use. Those computations are performed only at the PostScript level, which happens during conversion DVI → PS, so they're not available during the TeX run.

Comment: Yes ;) So I'm wondering how to convert that line into a number.

Comment: You have to use a number engine at the TeX level, say `fp` or `pgfmath` or `expl3`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, using `fp` worked perfectly. Having the question solved, how can I upvote or mark this one as solved? Is it helpful to uploading the new code?

Comment: Add a self-answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my answer with respect to egreg's comment:

```
\documentclass[dvips]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks, pstricks-add}
\usepackage{fp}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid = true](-4.5, -4.5)(4.5, 5)
    \def\radius{4\space}
    \def\Adeg{68\space}
    \def\Bdeg{30\space}

    \def\xp{2\space}
    \def\yp{1\space}
    \def\zp{1\space}

    \def\DistanceFromViewer{%
    \radius \Bdeg cos \Adeg sin mul mul \xp mul %
    \radius \Adeg cos \Bdeg cos mul mul \yp mul add %
    \radius \Bdeg sin mul \zp mul add %
    \radius dup mul sub abs %
    \radius div\space}

    \FPeval{\resultDistanceFromViewer}{%
    abs(\radius * cos(\FPpi * \Bdeg / 180) * sin(\FPpi * \Adeg / 180) * \xp + %
    \radius * cos(\FPpi * \Adeg / 180) * cos(\FPpi * \Bdeg / 180) * \yp + %
    \radius * sin(\FPpi * \Bdeg / 180) * \zp - %
    \radius * \radius) / (\radius)}

    \def\MinDist{0\space}
    \def\MaxDist{\radius 2 mul\space}
    \def\MinColor{40\space}
    \def\MaxColor{100\space}

    \def\mapDFVtoColor{%
    \DistanceFromViewer \MinDist sub %
    \MaxColor \MinColor sub mul %
    \MaxDist \MinDist sub div %
    \MinColor add}

    \FPeval{\resulmapDFVtoColor}{%
    (\resultDistanceFromViewer - \MinDist) * %
    (\MaxColor - \MinColor) / (\MaxDist - \MinDist) + \MinColor}

    \rput(1, 1){Distance: \psPrintValue{\DistanceFromViewer}}
    \rput(1, 0){Map: \psPrintValue{\mapDFVtoColor}}
    \rput(1, -1){Distance: \resultDistanceFromViewer}
    \rput(1, -2){Map: \resulmapDFVtoColor}

\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

It shows also a comparison between the results you get from the postscript code and the `fp` number crunching. Calling `\psset{linecolor = blue!\resulmapDFVtoColor}` works with that as well.